# Is there a way to list what `npm publish` will actually publish?

Tags: npm

[The docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) explain how to control which files are *not* sent to the npm registry when you run `npm publish`.

If you use `.npmignore`, or you're not using git that set of files differs from the set that are pushed to your source repo.

Is there a way to list the files that `npm publish` will send?

I know that `npm pack` will create a tarball that contains those files, but creating a tarball and then listing its contents seems a little clunky.

Comment: Not with `npm` itself, but there are some tools that you can use e.g. [pkgfiles](https://github.com/timoxley/pkgfiles), [irish-pub](https://github.com/thlorenz/irish-pub).

Comment: @eush77 if you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no such thing in `npm` (see [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6351)).

At the moment you can use some external tools that implement the functionality you're asking for, e.g. [pkgfiles](https://github.com/timoxley/pkgfiles) or [irish-pub](https://github.com/thlorenz/irish-pub).

Answer (score 1):

As of at least `npm@6`, you can run `npm publish --dry-run` to see what files are included in your package.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-publish